# Matlab, rgb2gray gives colour image as output

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Could you please clarify, how does function "rgb2gray" in Matlab work?

```
u=imread('C:\im1.jpg');
image(rgb2gray(u));
```

Info on original image:

ans =

```
       Filename: 'C:\im1.jpg'
    FileModDate: '09-Mar-2014 20:30:14'
       FileSize: 8653
         Format: 'jpg'
  FormatVersion: ''
          Width: 320
         Height: 240
       BitDepth: 24
      ColorType: 'truecolor'
FormatSignature: ''
NumberOfSamples: 3
   CodingMethod: 'Huffman'
  CodingProcess: 'Sequential'
        Comment: {}
```

I receive output image, but it is definitely not grayscale.. Just some image with very bright colouts. I couldn't find any clues in documentation - perhaps problems is related to color depth of original picture.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a link to the original image? Or perhaps one that has the same problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you have a gray image (2D array), the displayed color will depend on which colormap you use. You should set a gray colormap:

```
u = imread('C:\im1.jpg');
image(rgb2gray(u));
colormap(gray(256)) %// u is uint8, so 256 levels
```

See [`colormap` documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) for details

Comment: +1 Given that the default colormap is usually `jet`, that'll be it. This is why I like `imshow`.